# Reading and writing from file to a file in C

Tags: c, scanf

I have to write a program in C to read from a file and write to another file to created by the code. I am using the Mac terminal for Linux as required by the teacher (coding in xCode tho). So I am able to get it to compile using "gcc -o main2 main2.c" and also "./main2

The output is a garbled mess and I've been googling like crazy but have been unable to find out anything. I'm thinking the error is in my Scanf but I could be wrong. Any thoughts would be appreciated as to why this code isn't working as it should. Thanks.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "customer.h"
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int fileid;
    int status;
    int matchcount;

    customer jdoe;

    fileid = open("Consumerman", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
//"%d %20c %d-%d-%d (%50c||<%d %40c>) %30c %2c %d %f"

    matchcount = scanf ("%d %20[^<>]c %d-%d-%d %50[^<>]c %20[^<>]c %2c %d %g",  &jdoe.idnumber, jdoe.name, &jdoe.year, &jdoe.month, &jdoe.day, /*&jdoe.address, jdoe.street,*/ jdoe.stringstreet, jdoe.city, jdoe.state, &jdoe.zipcode, &jdoe.points);


    while((matchcount != 0) && (matchcount != EOF)){
        status = write(fileid, (void *) &jdoe, sizeof(jdoe));

        matchcount = scanf (" %d %20[^<>]c %d-%d-%d %50[^<>]c %20[^<>]c %2c %d %g",  &jdoe.idnumber, jdoe.name, &jdoe.year, &jdoe.month, &jdoe.day, /*&jdoe.address, jdoe.street,*/ jdoe.stringstreet, jdoe.city, jdoe.state, &jdoe.zipcode, &jdoe.points);


    }
    close(fileid);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `%20[^<>]c` --> `%20[^<>]`

Comment: Please provide sample input

Comment: Chux - I have fiddled with that before and didn't really get anything helpful

Comment: Karoly Horvath This would be a line from the file Customer.txt:

**2094936   <Charlie Vasquez>    1982-10-24     <556 E Weddell Dr>   <Sunnyvale>       CA       94089       1908.05**

Answer (score 0):

`scanf()` performs conversion on the input, while the `write()` system call just dumps `raw` data to a given file descriptor. You'll need to use a formatting function (like `printf()`) to get plain text output from (what appears to be) your data structure, for example:

```
FILE* file = fopen("Consumerman", "w");
fprintf(file, "%d\n", jdoe.idnumber);
fclose(file);
```

PS: Any particular reason you were using system calls in the first place?

Comment: Thank you for that response and I'm just using what the teacher taught us and told us to use. We've done our best with his examples and the system calls are all he has used. I will try that method.

Comment: @Digital_Reality I've been able to get it to print jdoe.idnumber but when I try to have it print all the parts, I get an error saying all my %c should be changed to %s for strings, however, when I do, the output (of course) gets messed up. Any help available?